# How can I make a 2d platformer character controller in Sprite Kit? (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I've asked a few times but haven't really found what I'm looking for. I need a simple character controller that allows my character to continuously move left if the left side of the screen is held and right side as well. When let go I would like the character to stop moving.

My GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let character = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "character"))
var move = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    //world
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)


    //character
    character.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, self.frame.size.height * 0.6)
    character.setScale(0.2)
    character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character.size)
    character.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    character.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.addChild(character)
    character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true




    //platform 1
    var platform = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform"))
    platform.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    platform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform.size)
    platform.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform.setScale(0.25)
    platform.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    platform.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    platform.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    self.addChild(platform)

    //platform 2
    var platformTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
    var platform2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
    platform2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.4, self.frame.size.height * 0.3)
    platform2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform2.size)
    platform2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform2.setScale(0.25)
    platform2.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    platform2.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    platform2.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    self.addChild(platform2)


    //platform main
    var platformTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
    var platform3 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
    platform3.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + platform3.size.height / 3)
    platform3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform3.size)
    platform3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform3.setScale(1)
    platform3.size.width = platform3.size.width * CGFloat(2.0)
    platform3.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    platform3.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    platform3.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    self.addChild(platform3)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame){
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -50, dy: 0))
        } else if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame){
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 0))
        }
    }



    func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        character.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)


    }




    func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */


    }
};
}
```

Comment: So Im guessing what you have now is every time you press, the character jerks one way or another and then stops because of 'applyImpulse'?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIGestureRecognizer` to track when the finger is pressed and held down. The `UILongPressGestureRecognize` is what you need. Check the official documentation here:
[Long Press Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

When the gesture recognizer is called, you could then apply the impulse in the same manner that you are doing now. However, you should probably turn off `friction` on your physics bodies everywhere since that will obviously decelerate whatever you want to move. If you really want friction to stay, then you can then use an `SKAction` and have the node move by a certain X. Then, run that action repeatedly.

The Long Press GestureRecognizer will change its state when the user lifts their finger. When that happens, all you have to do is - (if you are using the physics way): turn `velocity` of the node to zero OR (if you are using SKAction): stop the action.

edit: Here is more or less what you should have:

1. Implement the UILongPressGestureRecognizer:

   UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(performLongPress)];

then create a method:

```
-(int)performLongPress(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *){
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        //you know that the user just started pressing screen.
        if([gesture locationInView:self] == wherever you want it to be...){
             //apply your impulse here instead
        }
    }
}
```

then set friction to zero everywhere.

Comment: Thank You I will try this and reply.

Comment: Could you show me an example using my code so I can get an idea because I don't really understand it.

Comment: @DiegoMendoza read my edit, I put in some code to get you started

Comment: I will try but I am not sure if Objective-C works because I am using Swift. that is objective-c right? edit: I just tried and obj-c doesn't work. :( do you think you could translate to swift?? I read documentation but there are no examples on how to implement it.

Comment: yeah that is. obj-c won't work if you just copy and paste the code in as-is. you'll have to re-write it in Swift

Comment: I started iOS development in iOS 8 so I never learned Obj-C, I won't be able to re-write..

Comment: here let me explain what I wrote (I think that would probably help you the most): I first initialize the recognizer using the constructor `initWithTarget: Action:`. the action is a selector that calls a method inside of your scene. In the method I have as an argument the long press gesture recognizer. This allows me to check its state via `gesture.state`. see the documentation here for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer